# How to keep page numbering below text?

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, page-numbering

I have started writing my report using LaTeX. I have hid the page numbers for the first pages, table of contents included. However, after table of contents page numbers seems to be above the lowest point that the content reaches. I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\title{\bf Title\vspace{2cm}}
\author{\emph{Author:}\\author\vspace{0.5cm} \\ \emph{Supervisor:}\\supervisor\vspace{2cm}}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

and resetting counter after ToC like this :`\setcounter{page}{1}`
What do i have to change in order the page numbers to appear below my text?

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: The code you just posted doesn't reproduce the problem you mentioned; please add a proper minimal example.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with recluze regarding the selection of document class. You should not be using `article` class for a report.

However, if you want the page numbers to be uniformly placed at a particular height you can use `geometry` package (`footskip=.25in`) along with `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%<-------------to control headers and footers
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title of the report}
\author{your name}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} %<----to get page number below your text
\pagestyle{fancy} %<-------the page style itself
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1-13]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1-13]
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may remove `showframe` from geometry options in the final version.

Answer (score 0):

To write a report, you should use the `report` document class (or `memoir` if you want better output. I prefer it myself.) Use the `memoir` manual to find out how to separate `frontmatter`, `mainmatter` and `backmatter`. That should solve all the numbering issues.

If you want to hide the TOC from the TOC itself, use `\section*{Table of Contents}` (or `\chapter*{Table of Contents}` if you're using `report` or `memoir`). Then, post any follow up questions.